# Fill DataTable having one column as DateTime value and bind with DataGridView

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable, datetime-format, dataadapter

I have data from an excel file which contains one column as DateTime with a specific format. Now I retrieved data from the file using dataadapter and fill the datatable.

How can I change the DateTime column format into specific culture before binding datatable with datagridview?

Comment: What do you mean format into specific culture?

Comment: Formating datetime into specific culture provided by System.Globalization namespace. 

For example:
dateExcel.ToString(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the DefaultCellStyle property of the DateTime column of your DataGridView to format and display your DateTime values in a culture specific format.
Here is a small example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("dayofbirth", typeof(DateTime));

// Fill your data table
...

// Bind your data table against the grid view.    
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

// Set format styles for your date columns (after binding)
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = ci;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = ci.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I required. Thank you Hans.